# Using foreign keys with multiple primary key combinations

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a company table with the following fields:

```
CompanyID
EmailDomain1
EmailDomain2
EmailDomain3
...
```

I have another table t with the following fields:

```
CompanyID
EmailDomain
EmailDomainstat
```

The following are the constraints:

1. (CompanyID, emaildomain) should be unique in t;
2. If an emaildomain of a company gets deleted (email domain could be
   any of emaildomain1, emaildomain2 or emaildomain3), the
   corresponding companyID and EmailDomain combination should get
   automatically deleted.

For example, if a company Abc Inc. has 2 email domains abcinc.in and abc.org, and they plan to remove abcinc.in tomorrow, then I should have the corresponding entry in table t deleted.

How do I get this effect with the help of primary and foreign keys ? I know that the delete on cascade has to be used, but I have no clue on how to bind foreign keys with multiple combinations of primary keys.

Comment: Any time you're numbering columns, it's usually an indication that something's going wrong with your data model. Is there something *fundamental* about an email domain that means that it obviously is an `EmailDomain2` rather than an `EmailDomain1`?

Comment: I agree with @Damien, your data is probably not normalized. However, if you want/must to keep it that way, then you must use triggers. Primary and foreign keys can not help you in this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. No, emaildomain1 and emaildomain2 are indifferentiable.

Comment: Then I'd suggest that there should be a separate table that stores each email domain for a company as a separate row - note that this actually more cleanly maps to what you said yourself was wanted for part 2 - that an email domain now does actually get `DELETE`d (rather than what would happen in your model where a column actually gets `UPDATE`d to `NULL`). If you actually want to limit how many domains a company can have, that can be achieved with appropriate keys and a small auxiliary table.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Damien. I figured that out, and I am going to implement precisely that.